# Gnuplot, how to include a space character in key titles?

Tags: key, label, gnuplot, legend

I want to use key titles like "Best F" "Worst F" for a gnuplot 4.4 graph, when reading the data from a file, but I can't figure out how to put the space, e.g.:

```
Generation Best_F Worst_F Average_F
     5        4     9         5
     4        3     9         4
```

I tried writing in the file "Best F", "Best%20F" "Best\ F" but they get split, when read as column headers, or I get the ugly looking "%20".

```
plot for[col=2:4] data.dat using 1:col title columnheader(col)
```

Or is there a way to do a character substitution, like "Best_F"%" "->"Best F"? replace("_", "\ ", columheader(col))?

I am using terminals wxt and pngcairo (no latex).
Thanks

Comment: Could you post an example script?  A quick test for me using gnuplot 4.2.6 wxt terminal shows no problem with `plot x title "Best F"`.

Comment: "But they get split" -- Can you elaborate?  What do you mean by that?

Comment: The problem is that the titles are read from the file, they are the columnheaders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [Datastrings](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-5000011) section of the manual (that's an old version, but unfortunately later ones haven't been published in HTML), strings in data files are delimited with double quotes. If I modify your example data file to be like this, then I get titles with spaces, when I run it under gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 1 (with datastrings enabled).

```
Generation "Best F" "Worst F" "Average F"
     5        4     9         5
     4        3     9         4
```

Program:

```
plot for[col=2:4] "data.txt" using 1:col title columnheader(col)
```

Output excerpt:

> [image]

Comment: Wow, thanks.  I suspect I must have written 'Best F' instead of "Best F" the first time I tried.  It works with double quotes, but does not work with single :).

Answer (score 0):

With the [Enhanced Postscript](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node411.html) you can create spaces of variable width:

```
Generation Best&{x}F Worst&{x}F Average&{x}F
     5        4         9           5
     4        3         9           4
```

where you can replace x with a string of desired length.
However, this requires a terminal that allows

```
set termoption enhanced
```

This is especially useful if you want to use`awk`to process files based on the headers and autolabel them in gnuplot based on the columnheader.