# Gnuplot: Violin plot with data from file

Tags: gnuplot, violin-plot

I created a script to plot the columns of a dataset using violin plots to show the distribution of the data points starting from the [Gnuplot Demo Scripts](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/violinplot.html). However, I can't solve the following error:

> "violinplot.gnu", line 27: all points y value undefined!

Does anyone have any idea?

The script:

```
reset

set terminal pdfcairo size 20,14 enhanced font 'Times,28'
set output 'violinplot.0.pdf'

set datafile separator ','

set table $kdensity1
plot 'profile.csv' using 2:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 10. with filledcurves above y lt 9 title 'B'
unset table
unset key

print $kdensity1

set border 2
#unset margins
#unset xtics
set ytics nomirror rangelimited
set title "Distribution of times in milliseconds"

set boxwidth 0.075
set style fill solid bo -1
set errorbars lt black lw 5

set xrange [-6:6]
plot $kdensity1 using (1 + $2/1.):1 with filledcurve x=1 lt 10, \
     $kdensity1 using (1 - $2/1.):1 with filledcurve x=1 lt 10
```

The dataset is in a CSV format as follows (and each column contains time in milliseconds):

```
1,1814,604,840,1306,13623
2,2195,68,908,1380,14416
3,1173,70,887,512,14301
4,1286,112,982,1541,9549
5,630,97,869,1321,5725
6,1227,689,917,393,4700
7,3402,357,951,500,5431
8,3429,120,969,1661,6281
...
```

Gnuplot Version 5.2 patchlevel 2

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is simple but "nasty" and hidden.

Your input data is comma separated. However, if you plot to a table via `set table $kdensity` the default column separator is whitespace. That's why gnuplot doesn't find any data in column 2.

I guess since gnuplot 5.2.2. you could set `set table $kdensity separator comma`. But in order to get a comma as separator you have to use the "plotting style" `with table` (e.g. `plot FILE u 1:2 w table`). However, `with table` and `smooth ...` do not work together. Either you use `with table` and you will get the comma but not "smoothed" or you "smooth" and you will not get the comma.

Two possible solutions:

- after plotting to the smoothed table set your separator to whitespace (see example below).

or alternatively,

- change your input data to whitespace separated.

If you want plot the original (comma separated) data as well, then you have two different column separators. Then you have to apply [another workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73419428/7295599).

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.2.2)

```
### violin plot with comma separated input data
reset session

# create some random test data (comma separated)
set table $Data separator comma
    set samples 100
    n = 0
    plot for [i=1:3] '+' u (n=n+1):(invnorm(rand(0))*i*25 +i*200) w table
unset table

set datafile separator ','

set table $kdensity
    set samples 1000
    plot $Data using 2:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 10.
unset table

set datafile separator whitespace
set key noautotitle
set style fill solid 0.7

plot $kdensity u (1 + $2/1.):1 w filledcurves x=1 lt 10, \
           ''  u (1 - $2/1.):1 w filledcurves x=1 lt 10
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]